# CSS: Submenú flotante

Tags: html, css

Antes de nada, decir que no tengo ni idea de `CSS` y es este motivo por el que llevo días intentando hacer que un submenú sea ¿flotante? y no me desplace el contenido inferior como se puede apreciar en las fotos.

¿Hay solución? ¿Qué se puede hacer para solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="mainpage.php" class="selected">Main Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="allGraph.php">Extra Info</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Principal</li>
        <li>Diario</li>
        <li>Semanal</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pastProfile.php">Historial</a></li>
    <li><a href="notes.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues en el estilo coloca lo siguiente:

```
#menu{
   z-index: 30;
   position: fixed;
}
```

z-index es para indicar que capa es. Entre mas alto el numero, mas alto el numero, mas por sobre otros estara.

position: fixed, es para indicarle que quieres que donde quede, esta sea "fijo", pero se mueva contigo. Como lo es por ej el chat de facebook.

Luego puedes definir con

```
position-top: 0px;
position-left: 0px;
```

Tu defines el "0", a lo que necesitas que se posicione.

EXTRA:

Contestando a tu reciente pregunta en el comentario:

Pues si otorgas a #menu{} el max-width, le estas colocando a todo el menú dicho atributo. Aquí hay dos opciones, o creas una nueva clase y la llamas del css, o lo colocas en la misma tab. Para mi, entendiendo que es solo una propiedad colocaremos para esta única tab y es solo un atributo, seria bueno colocarlo dentro de la tab, como se hace eso? te muestro a continuación

```
<li style="max-width: 0px"><a href="allGraph.php">Extra Info</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Principal</li>
        <li>Diario</li>
        <li>Semanal</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

La propiedades la defines en **Style**, igual que un archivo css. Considerando que era un caso único, es por ello que lo definimos acá. Sin embargo si deseas ser mas organizado, entonces hacerlo como siempre es mejor.

```
<li class="extraInfo"><a href="allGraph.php">Extra Info</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Principal</li>
        <li>Diario</li>
        <li>Semanal</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

y luego del archivo css lo añades como al principio.

```
.extraInfo{
   max-width: 0px;
}
```

**Nota:** Tu defines el ancho máximo que desees.

**Nota2:** Si defines un id, luego lo llamas del css con #id, si es una clase .clase, y si es un tag como puede ser un div, simplemente colocas div.

Recuerda después borrar el max-width del css .menu{}

Comment: ¡Funciona! aunque ... algunos peros, pero creo que me valdrá.
Una cosa, si te fijas en la foto, cuando paso por **Extra Info** y se despliega el submenú, se abre un espacio entre **Extra Info** e **Historial** ¿Cómo se podría solucionar?

Comment: Eso puedes solucionarlo con max-width: 0px; considera que cuando coloco 0px, es para que tu definas cuanto es lo que querrás ponerle de pixeles. La propiedad define cuanto es el máximo de ancho puede ser algo.

Comment: Jolín. Solucionado. Súper bien

Comment: Que bueno que hayas podido solucionarlo. Éxito en tu proyecto

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problema. El submenú de **Extra Info** se despliega bien pero en un tamaño incorrecto. el ancho = ancho del menú principal, cuando debería ser ancho = ancho de la opción **Extra Info**. ¿A qué crees que es debido?. He probado añadir _background:_ pero no funciona bien

Comment: te añadi la respuesta en "Extra" de la misma respuesta. Y unos tips para que vayas entendiendo como se maneja css. Saludos!

Comment: Pues no, no funciona y seguro que es por que te lo he explicado mal ¿Alguna opción (email) de mandarte un video o foto para que veas el efecto real? De todas formas, _max-width_ no lo tenía debajo de _#menú_ si no debajo de _#menú ul_

Comment: jmsepulveda@sb.cl

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo buenas te recomiendo que uses Boostrap es una de las soluciones espero que te sirva:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #211f1f">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.qapaq.pe/" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
                <img src="img/Qapaq.png" style="width: 45px; height: 40px; "
                    class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav" runat="server">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reportes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="FrmAtenderTarea.aspx">Registrar Tarea </a></li>

                        <%--<li><a href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Mensual </a></li>--%>

                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reporte Mensual <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Por Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmTodasOficinas.aspx">Reporte por Todas las Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmReporZonas.aspx">Report por Zonas</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="FrmanioxZona.aspx">Reporte por Zona y Año</a></li>
                                 <%-- <li><a href="ReportImagen.aspx">Consultar Recibos</a></li>--%>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gestión <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="SeguimientoAtender.aspx">Gestiones de Servicios</a></li>

                        <%--<li><a href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Mensual </a></li>--%>

                      <%--  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reporte Mensual <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Por Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmTodasOficinas.aspx">Reporte por Todas las Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmReporZonas.aspx">Report por Zonas</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="FrmanioxZona.aspx">Reporte por Zona y Año</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="ReportImagen.aspx">Consultar Recibos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>--%>

                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="Ul1" runat="server">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reportes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="FrmAtenderTarea.aspx">Registrar Tarea </a></li>

                        <%--<li><a href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Mensual </a></li>--%>

                       <%-- <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reporte Mensual <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Por Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmTodasOficinas.aspx">Reporte por Todas las Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmReporZonas.aspx">Report por Zonas</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="FrmanioxZona.aspx">Reporte por Zona y Año</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>--%>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gestión <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="SeguimientoAtenderHOST.aspx">Gestiones de Servicios</a></li>

                        <%--<li><a href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Mensual </a></li>--%>

                      <%--  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reporte Mensual <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="Frm_Report_Excel.aspx">Reporte Por Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmTodasOficinas.aspx">Reporte por Todas las Oficinas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FrmReporZonas.aspx">Report por Zonas</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="FrmanioxZona.aspx">Reporte por Zona y Año</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="ReportImagen.aspx">Consultar Recibos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>--%>

                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>






        </div>
        <p class="navbar-text" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;">Financiera QAPAQ </p>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega algo de contexto a tu respuesta, Lee: **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos `li` que tengan un `ul` deben ser posicionados relativamente, es decir, `position: relative` para que la lista interna **sea posicionada tomando como referencia la posición de** `li`.

```
nav > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

En este ejemplo, las listas internas no serán visibles hasta que el puntero se pose sobre el elemento `li` padre. Cuando pase esto, la lista interna se posicionará **debajo del elemento** `li` de modo flotante. El `z-index` es **para darle prioridad a un elemento dentro de un stack** (uno encima de otro) respecto a los demás elementos.